# Match words which contain *N* times a certain letter

Tags: regex, matlab

I am trying to match words which contain *N* times a letter (with *regexp* of MATLAB) and by this I do not mean finding only repeated letters, which I could do it like this:

```
\w*(\w)\1\w*
```

A simple example would be to find the following regular expression:
Match words which contain **3** times the letter **a**. If the given string is:

hallo b**a**n**a**n**a** alabama oklahoma c**a**n**aa**n

then the matched words should be:

*banana* and *canaan*. All the others contain less or more **a**.

Any help is appreciated
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\b(?:[^a\s]*a){3}[^a\s]*\b
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/10

Comment: @knedlsepp with a slight modification it works. You just have to replace the beginning character of the word `\b`. The following should work:
`\<(?:[^0\s]*0){5}[^0\s]*\>`